# "browse..." button has no hover effect

Tags: bug, chat, design, uploader

In chat, when you upload pictures, the "upload button" does not have a hover effect like the "upload" and "cancel" buttons do. Here is what I mean:

> [image: broken upload button]

However, with the other buttons, they have a press-down effect:

> [image: ok button]

I'm guessing this is a bug with the css?

**Firefox, Ubuntu 14.04.2LTS**
**Chrome, Also Ubuntu 14.04.2LTS**

---

Note: This is just hovering over the button, not pressing it
Another note: The upload button does not have a press mouse, but the cancel button does. Its just that my screenshot tool can't capture that.

Comment: That's because the browse button isn't a standalone button like the other two, but rather part of the `<input type="file" />` HTML control. Blame the browser.

Comment: Will try this with chrome soon

Comment: @ShadowWizard Can reproduce in chrome

Comment: If I reduce the width of the `<input type="file" />` it is fixed (repro-ed and tested on IE11/Win7)

Comment: @rene Yep. Blame the devs

Comment: haha, I was just kidding (by "blame the browser" ;-)). Oops.

Comment: AHHH! With the bounty, why still no devs come to fix?

Answer (score 7):

Okay. Got more on the bottom of this. The source of the issue is that SE already changes the UI (unlike as my previous answer) of the file button by using a shadow `input type="file"` element in the background.

The `browse` button is:

```
<input class="button" type="button" name="choose-file" id="choose-file" value="browse…" style="width: 7em; margin-left: 5px;">
```

This should have been:

```
<button class="button" type="button" name="choose-file" id="choose-file" value="browse…" style="width: 7em; margin-left: 5px;">
```

Then it shows the hover.

Comment: Sorry but you're wrong. As [this test proves](http://jsfiddle.net/es8dgj43/), the input of type file does support hover effect, they only have to attach it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: It changes the text hover, not the button hover.

Comment: hmm.... let me see about background...

Comment: @ShadowWizard: `background-color` doesn't work. Tested already.

Comment: Oh well, guess you're right then - it's kind of surprising they were able to style it same way as the other buttons. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Thanks for the pointer. Got it diagnosed now.

Comment: ha! Didn't notice they use a custom button... guess I didn't dig deep enough. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: It was stuffed away in another `div`, but Chrome hit the wrong element when doing 'Inspect element'.